# Facebook Javascript SDK , Throws unexpected Iframe Errors occasionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js, x-frame-options

So I'm using facebook posts embedding plugin to load facebook posts in my NEXT.JS Website through their Javascript SDK. I first get my post URLs through the graph API , then I send the URLs to FB Post Embedder to load the facebook posts.
The Errors I receive :

Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Here is my layout.js Code:

```
<html lang="en">
      <head>
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/49216970f8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
        <Navbar/>
        {children}
        <Footer/>
      </body>
</html>
```

Here is my Component Code Where it is Loaded:

```
"use client"

import axios from "axios"
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";



const MediaPage = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/1420874058216169/posts', {
                    params: {
                        access_token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_API_TOKEN,
                        fields: 'id,message,created_time,permalink_url'
                    }
                });
                setData(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    if (data) {
        console.log(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.FB) {
            window.FB.XFBML.parse();
        }
    }, [data]);

    return (
        <div className="p-40 bg-black font-bold flex items-center justify-center w-full min-h-screen">
            {data ? (
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-10">
                    {data.data.map((post) => (
                        <div key={post.id} className="w-full bg-white text-black">
                            <div className="fb-post" data-href={post.permalink_url} data-show-text="true"></div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}

export default MediaPage
```

Ive followed all the instructions thoroughly and sometimes it works by displaying the posts while other times it will throw errors. I can't figure out why its so inconsistent and why it doesn't work sometimes.

Comment: `access_token: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FACEBOOK_API_TOKEN,` - exposing your access token in client-side code, is just wrong to begin with.

Comment: thanks, I've fixed that, but the problem still persists.